# Обособляется ли оборот "лишь дойдя..."?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

"Лишь дойдя до самого дна можно всплыть на поверхность."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае деепричастным оборотом является часть текста: "лишь дойдя до самого дна". Частица "лишь" - тоже входит в оборот.
Соответственно, правильно писать:

> Лишь дойдя до самого дна, можно всплыть на поверхность.